# Objects from registerhelper in Handlebars.js / Browserify bundle not printing in Django app on some servers

Tags: django, handlebars.js, browserify

I have a Django site that I'm deploying where I'm using Handlebars.js for templateing. I'm using Browserify to bundle the Javascript. I'm using registerhelper in Handlebars.js to iterate over some objects and print them in modals on click. A sample of this code is below.

I have my Django app deployed on a live dev server (Digital Ocean) and these text boxes are being populated without problem. When I pushed to the production server (university server) these text boxes are not getting populated. Otherwise the Django app is working fine on both live dev and production servers. There are no errors in the console.

The servers are similar but not totally the same. Both are running Ubuntu and Python 2.7 and have the same pip dependancies. We are using the same bundle.js from Browserify on both servers.

I don't know if this is a code problem or a dependency problem and it's driving me nuts because the deployment completely works on the live dev server. Any advice would be welcome.

Below is an example of my Handlebars code:

```
{{#countryListTitle attributes.works 'Projects'}}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"><h3>Projects</h3></div>
    {{#each attributes.works}}
        {{#countryListContent attributes ../attributes.full_name   'Projects'}}
        {{/countryListContent}}
    {{/each}}
</div>                          
 {{else}}
 {{/countryListTitle}}
```

Below is an example of my related Javascript code:

```
registerHBHelpers: function(){
Handlebars.registerHelper('countryListTitle', function(works, needle, options) {
    var yes = 0;

    $.each(works, function(key, value) {
        if (value.attributes.work_types[0].attributes.name == needle) {
            yes = 1;
        }
    });

    if(yes == 1) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('countryListContent', function(attributes, full_name, type, options) {
    var output = '';
    var periodicals = '';
    var publishers = '';

    for(var i=0, l=attributes.work_types.length; i<l; i++) {
        // add item name if the type is the type passed to the helper
        if (attributes.work_types[i].attributes.name == type) {
            output = output + '<div class="col-sm-12"><h4>' +  attributes.title + '</h4></div>';

            // add publication info if a publication
            if (attributes.publicationinfo) {
                var d = new Date(attributes.publicationinfo.date_published);
                var month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
                var year = d.getFullYear();
                switch (month)
                {
                   case 1:
                       month = 'January';
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       month = 'February';
                       break;
                   case 3: 
                       month = 'March';
                       break;
                   case 4: 
                       month = 'April';
                       break;
                   case 5: 
                       month = 'May';
                       break;
                   case 6: 
                       month = 'June';
                       break;
                   case 7: 
                       month = 'July';
                       break;
                   case 8: 
                       month = 'August';
                       break;
                   case 9: 
                       month = 'September';
                       break;
                   case 10: 
                       month = 'October';
                       break;
                   case 11: 
                       month = 'November';
                       break;
                   case 12: 
                       month = 'December';
                       break;
                   default: 
                       month = '';
                       break;
                }

                if (attributes.publicationinfo.periodicals.length > 0) {
                    periodicals = attributes.publicationinfo.periodicals[0].trim() + ', ';
                }

                if (attributes.publicationinfo.publishers.length > 0) {
                    publishers = attributes.publicationinfo.publishers[0].trim() + ', ';
                }
                output = output + '<div class="col-sm-12"><p class="modal-fine-print">' + periodicals + publishers + 'Published ' + month + ' ' + year + '</p></div>';

                // add buffer of no unordered lists will appear
                if (attributes.topics.length === 0 && attributes.faculty.length === 0) {
                    output = output + '<div class="buffer"></div>';
                } 


            }

            if (attributes.faculty.length > 0) {
                output = output + '<div class="col-sm-12"><p class="modal-list-first-element"><strong>Faculty</strong></p><p>';

                for(var e=0, p=attributes.faculty.length; e<p; e++) {
                    if (attributes.faculty[e].attributes.home_page !== '') {
                        output = output + '<a href="' + attributes.faculty[e].attributes.home_page + '" target="_blank">' + attributes.faculty[e].attributes.full_name + '</a><br />';
                    } else {
                        output = output + '' + attributes.faculty[e].attributes.full_name + '<br />';
                    }

                }                   
                output = output + '</p></div>';
            }

            if (attributes.topics.length > 0) {
                output = output + '<div class="col-sm-12"><p class="modal-list-first-element"><strong>Topics</strong></p><p>';

                for(var h=0, m=attributes.topics.length; h<m; h++) {
                    output = output + attributes.topics[h].attributes.name + '<br />';
                }

                output = output + '</p></div>';
            }

            output = output + '<div class="buffer"></div>';                     

        }
    }

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(output);

});
  },
```

Lee

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - there was a change in an object name in the database. It was hard to debug, but simple problem in the end.